# Saving Visio 2000 File to GIF, Final Output does not fit

Tags: microsoft-visio, gif, microsoft-visio-2003

Good day, I am using a Visio 2000 (yes this version is very old, but this is what the company requires) I am to save the file to GIF image but the final output does not get the whole image correctly

[image]

I have already format the Page size to for the drawing content, but still having the same incorrect output.

[image]

[image]

Please advise

Comment: I don't have enough experience in Visio to post an answer, but I would not look for the page size options, as this is solely related to printing. I'd look in the drawing scale tab instead.

Comment: very much appreciated, will post the screenshot of drawing scale

Comment: What if you export to another format, then convert that to GIF? (I'm not hopeful, but worth a try)

Comment: still the same output.

Comment: I would change the scale to something else, just try and see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't go back to Visio 2000, the earliest I still have active is Visio 2003 and that doesn't show the same problem.

However, I can tell you a way around the problem.

Draw a box around all the shapes leaving a suitable margin. Format this box shape to be No Fill and set the line colour to be a very pale grey so it is only just visible (but just visible enough so you know it is there). Now do your save to GIF.

Comment: Hi, Seems there is no transparent options for the box shape

Comment: Even better, Format -> Fill - set to No fill.

Comment: Hi, no options for that also, but as a workaround, i did Shape > Sent to back.

Comment: No fill options on the format menu? Really?

Comment: there's a fill options but there is no "No Fill" option there

Comment: Look at the options in the Fill Pattern drop-down.